# Minecraft FallingSand is Strangely Permanent

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Minecraft server, and when I use the `FallingSand` entity along with `/execute` on a clock, the `FallingSand` acts like it has `Time:1`. I tried setting `Time:0`, but it still does the same thing. All the `FallingSand` is gone when the command block that summons it is removed.

What is going on? What can I do to not let the `FallingSand` disappear?

Comment: This works on a singleplayer world.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your server may have the command blocks disabled.

To turn them on, go to your server file, open "server.properties" with a text editor (example: notepad), and search for `enable-command-block`, and set that to `true`, save the changes, and run the server.

Comment: No, command blocks are completely on.

Comment: I can do other commands with them.